# How to get option value on change AND on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that it is possible to do in two functions, but I am not sure how to make it in one.

```
$("#purchase_sub_type").change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == 15) {
       console.log('is 15');
   }
   else {
      console.log('not 15');
   }
});
```

This is example code. Problem is that this code works only on change, not when value is loaded form DB on page reload. Is there simple way to add current val to this function? I know that it is possible adding another function, but in that way code gets ugly and repeats.

Comment: try appending `.change()` to trigger it right onload.

Comment: Code need not get ugly and repeat: place your logic in a separate function and call that from two (or more) places...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger the change event so the code fires

```
$("#purchase_sub_type").change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == 15) {
       console.log('is 15');
   }
   else {
      console.log('not 15');
   }
}).change();  //or .trigger("change");
```

Comment: wow, that was fast and simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is good idea to give function a name.

```
var field = $("#purchase_sub_type");

function log () {
    if(field.val() == 15) {
       console.log('is 15');
    }
    else {
       console.log('not 15');
    }
};

field.change(log);
log();
```